# How can we log into a webserver using username password csrftoken and csrfmiddlewaretoken

Tags: objective-c, swift, django

I am trying to log into a server using my authentication(username and password) for app development purpose with swift 4. However my server requires csfrtoken and csrfmiddlewaretoken. How can I extract the csrfmiddlewaretoken value and make a Post request to log with all the other authentication?

Comment: Most mobile applications use some kind of API with an authorization key rather than the traditional session-based systems. As such, disabling CSRF for your API is pretty common.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do much with the server. I just need to be able to log in the server to parse the json file. The problem resides in the csrfmiddlewaretoken which I need to extract. However it is in the html format and its value change after each session.

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but could you consider to accept my answer? It solves the described problem and helps me here at SO.

Answer (score 2):

Keep [tadmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) comment in mind. If you really want to do it the way as you described it in your question you would need to make a `GET` request in order to parse the `CSRF` token of your desired login page. The token should be located inside the login form.

I have added a bash script to extract the token from `stackoverflow` as a reference:

```
fkey=`curl https://stackoverflow.com/users/login? | grep -P -o '(?<=value\=\")\w*(?=\")'`   
echo $fkey  # got the token      

# make a post request with the freshly parsed token
curl -L -c cookies -d 'fkey='$fkey'&ssrc=head&email=MY_MAIL_ADDRESS&password=MY_PASSWORD&oauth_version=&oauth_server=&openid_username=&openid_identifier=' https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=he$        

# finally browse the site with your obtained cookies
curl -b cookies https://stackoverflow.com/users/7727583/yannic-hamann
```

It is convenient to set up a token-based authentication method via the [`Django REST framework`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication). But this is only an option in case you are developing your own `API`.

Comment: Don't forget that in conjunction with the CSRF token you'll need to capture the cookie(s) associated with the site and send those back on subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added this to my bash example.

Comment: Using a Get request I was able to parse the csrftoken inside the login form

Comment: Good, that's the only token you should need. Sniff the ``POST`` packet of your login request in order to locate other required parameters.